# How to correctly serialise thread access to a flag controlling a loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

I have a function, f1, that contains a simple loop, which is controlled via a boolean flag. The flag is not written to inside f1.

I have another function that clears the flag.

The two functions are called on different threads.

If I lock the mutex before entering the loop in f1, then f2 will not be able to acquire it in order to clear the flag.

If I don't lock the mutex before entering the loop in f1, then the flag is unprotected. Does that matter, given that the function only reads it?

My question is do I *need* to protect the flag before entering the loop in f1, given that it is only read? If so, how?

Do I even need the mutex if the flag is only written to in one place?

Am I missing something fundamental?

TIA

```
class X
{
public:
    X() :
        m_thread(),
        m_isDone(false),
        m_mutex()
    {
        m_thread = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread( [=]{ run(); } ));
    }

    ~X()
    {
        // tell the thread to exit
        m_isDone = true;

        // wait for the thread to terminate
        m_thread->join();
    }

    void f1()
    {
        // locking the mutex will prevent f2 from clearing the flag
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        while (!m_isDone)
        {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }

    void f2()
    {
        // lock the mutex
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_isDone = true;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_thread;
    bool m_isDone;
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
};
```

Comment: It's not only read -- another thread is writing.  Also, instead of using a mutex, you could use an `atomic`.  Finally, on x86, bools are already atomic.

Comment: @John I don't see how there can be any architecture that could write a single bit non atomic ;) Doesn't make any differencee though, the visibility guarantees are just as important as atomicity. And while x86 is pretty strong there too, compilers certainly exploit such options - so no wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
bool m_isDone;
```

to:

```
std::atomic<bool> m_isDone;
```

That will make your reading and writing to `m_isDone` guaranteed atomic (which you need to do since it's being read and written in different threads). `atomic` also obviates the need for any sort of mutex, lock, etc.

Note that in your solution, `f1` holds the lock *forever*, so `f2` would never be able to acquire it anyway. The correct solution with locks is a more complicated and unnecessary:

```
bool isDone() { // easily replaced by atomic load
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    return m_isDone;
}

void f1() {
    while (!isDone()) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: On x86, you don't even need the atomic.

Comment: @JohnDibling You only need the atomic if you want to avoid the compiler optimizing the loop into `if (!m_isDone) { while(1) {...} }`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `std::atomic<bool>` will do the most efficient thing on the particular platform. And based on what @Casey said, you do need it anyway (at the very least, you'd have to make it `volatile`...)

Comment: @Barry if you're using volatile for any concurrency purpose you've just written a bug. The only correct solution here is std::atomic or a heavier synchronization primitive.

Comment: Read and upvoted, doesn't change the fact that "at the very least, you'd have to make it volatile" is wrong.